# Remove onerror tag in img field with twig

Tags: javascript, html, security, twig

I want to display HTML with twig.

Today, I do it like this:

```
{{ content | raw }}
```

But, if my content contains this line:

```
<img src=# onerror=alert(1) />
```

The alert is displayed.

If I use:

```
{{ content | escape }}
```

It doesn't work.

Do you know can I fix this security problem ?

Comment: You wrote twice `{{ content | raw }}`, is that correct?

Comment: argh, fixed. thank you ;)

Comment: Have tried the [`escape` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/filter.html) ?

Comment: I tried `escape` and `escape('js')`...

Comment: Never used twig, but [this](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#escaper-extension) looks promising. Sorry if it is not helpful.

Comment: This is not twig's task - you should do correct input sanitization, with html purifier, for example.

Comment: Thank you @Maerlyn, I installed html purifier.

Answer (score 0):

It's working as expected, the image 404s and errors.

Comment: "the image 404s and errors"? Can you explain please?

Comment: You've set the src of the image to be a hash, which will fail to load as it's not a valid URI. Which will then cause a 404 and then trigger the a dom error event to fire on the image showing the alert.

Comment: The raw filter allows you to return unsanitized content to the screen where as the escape filter will stop you from outputting HTML directly to the screen. 

You need to sanitise your content before you output it to scre